# Qt - Some questions about a header file

Tags: c++, qt

I have some questions about this header file from the `C++ GUI Programming with Qt 4` book:

```
#ifndef GOTOCELLDIALOG_H //Check if GOTOCELLDIALOG_H has not been defined previously
#define GOTOCELLDIALOG_H
#include <QDialog>
#include "ui_gotocelldialog.h"

class GoToCellDialog: public QDialog,
public Ui::GoToCellDialog {
    Q_OBJECT
    public: GoToCellDialog(QWidget * parent = 0);
    private slots: void on_lineEdit_textChanged();
};

#endif
```

1- I know what `#define` means. But, what is its use here? I mean, why are we trying to `#define` a *header file*?

2- Since I inherited `QDialog` and `Ui::GoToCellDialog`, why are we `#include`ing them?

3- What is `Q_OBJECT`? Why isn't it terminated by a semicolon?

4- What is this constructor `GoToCellDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);` trying to tell us?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This is called a header guard. It makes repeated inclusion of that header *idempotent*, i.e.

```
#include "gotocelldialog.h"
#include "gotocelldialog.h"
```

does the same as

```
#include "gotocelldialog.h"
```

This may look weird. In practice, this happens indirectly. Just look at how often "qobject.h" gets included in a single file.

2) You can only use types that are already defined before. The `#include` brings in the declaration you need.

3) `Q_OBJECT` is part of the Qt system. It's a macro, and defines a few standard members in your class. Those members support features like signals/slots.

4) Qt widgets may or may not have parents. If they don't have a parent, they're independent windows. If they do have parents, they're part of the parent window and are destroyed with the parent window.

The `(QWidget *parent = 0)` argument list is C++'s way to denote a default argument. If you do not pass an explicit value for the parent, it will be 0 (`NULL`). This stands for "no parent". Hence, you can create a parentless `GoToCellDialog` in two ways: either `new GoToCellDialog(0)` or `new GoToCellDialog`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Just small things if you can just explain. What is meant by `macro` in this context? And, What are examples of members that `Q_OBJECT` defines?

Comment: "macro" in this context is just the regular preprocessor-defined macro from C and C++. It's a straightforward literal text replacement, before the compiler starts. The members defined by the `Q_OBJECT` differ between Qt versions. This isn't a problem because you don't use them directly, but via the Qt functions.

Answer (score 1):

1) This is pattern to prevent multiple declarations of a same types.

2) If your header files uses types you need to either #include the type definitions or make a forward declaration.

3) Q_OBJECT is a macro that qt's moc tool will use to expand the class declaration to include QObject specific declarations.

4) Each graphical widget has parent/child relationship. Default constructor will then associate your new widget into its parent by passing the parent as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you just explain `#define` in more detail in the context of this code if possible? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. The use of `#define` here is to define the include guard if it was not previously defined yet. The first `#ifndef` checks if that include guard has already been defined somewhere, if it hasn't it will define it on line 2 with `#define`.

An include guard per [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) article:

> In the C and C++ programming languages, an #include guard,
>   sometimes called a macro guard, is a
>   particular construct used to avoid the
>   problem of double inclusion when
>   dealing with the #include directive.

1. You're including them so the linker knows where to find it's definition.
2. Is a macro...
3. That constructor tells you it takes a QWidget pointer and this parameter is defaulted to NULL, so you can use the ctor without passing this parameter.  That means however you should then NOT use this parameter in the class, as using a NULL pointer is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What do you mean by the *include guard* here? Can you explain what `#define` is doing in more detail if possible? Thanks

Comment: @user: I edited my question to include a quote from an article and a link to it.